# Invalid Identifier error message on left outer join using subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, left-join

This query only works if i replace the top select columns with "*". I've been reading through the other questions that are similar to mine but i haven't been able to apply their logic to my situation. All of the subqueries are the same except that they change based on the state in the "where" clauses.

There are far more successes everyday. Failures and warnings don't happen happen everyday so they have some null values that I would like to make into 0's. I want all of the successes, warnings, and failures to be related to the a.Start_date.

```
        Select a.START_DATE, a.Successes, b.START_DATE, b.Failures, c.START_DATE, c.WARNINGS

        FROM

        (
                Select 

                        (Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                             WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                             WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                             WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                        END) "START_DATE",
                    NVL(count(job_id),0) as "Successes"
            from NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V
            where State = 1

            and
            (:P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Tiny' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 1
            OR

            :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Small' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 1 AND 
                            (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 5
            OR

            :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Medium' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 5 AND 
                            (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 20
            OR
            :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Large' AND ((1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 20)
            OR
            :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER NOT IN('Small','Medium','Large','Tiny') AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 0)

            group by Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                             WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                             WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                             WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                        END
            order by Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                             WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                             WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                             WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                        END

        ) a
        left outer join

        (
                   Select 

                            (Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                                 WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                                 WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                                 WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                            END) "START_DATE",
                        nvl(count(job_id),0) as "Failures"
                from NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V
                where State = 3

                and
                (:P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Tiny' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 1
                OR

                :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Small' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 1 AND 
                                (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 5
                OR

                :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Medium' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 5 AND 
                                (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 20
                OR
                :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Large' AND ((1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 20)
                OR
                :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER NOT IN('Small','Medium','Large','Tiny') AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 0)
                group by Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                                 WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                                 WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                                 WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                            END
                order by Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                                 WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                                 WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                                 WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                            END

        ) b
        on
        a.START_DATE = b.START_DATE

        left outer join

        (
        Select 

                    (Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                         WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                         WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                         WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                    END) "START_DATE",
                nvl(count(job_id),0) as "Warnings"
        from NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V
        where State = 2



        and
        (:P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Tiny' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 1
        OR

        :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Small' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 1 AND 
                        (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 5
        OR

        :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Medium' AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 5 AND 
                        (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 20
        OR
        :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Large' AND ((1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 20)
        OR
        :P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER NOT IN('Small','Medium','Large','Tiny') AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 0)
        group by Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                         WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                         WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                         WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                    END
        order by Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                         WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
                         WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
                         WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
                    END

        ) c

        on
        a.START_DATE = c.START_DATE
        ORDER BY
        a.START_DATE
```

At the end, I would like to have the results be something like:

```
Start_Date  Successes  Warnings  Failures
6/1/2015            5         0         3
........            8        15         4
6/30/2015           9         1         0
```

Comment: Can you ever have a day with failures or warnings, but no successes? This won't report those if it can happen.

Comment: There are generally over 1000 successes on a given day even with the most demanding parameters set! Thank you for pointing that out but I believe that it is pretty much impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used quoted identifiers for (some of) the aliases in your subqueries, so you have to quote those in the outer select too, and exactly match the case you used:

```
Select a.START_DATE, a."Successes",
  b.START_DATE, b."Failures",
  c.START_DATE, c."Warnings"
...
```

Quoted identifiers are a pain. If you want the column titles to be mixed-case you could use unquoted identifiers in the subqueries and apply a final quoted name in ther outer query as another alias; or let the client handle that display issue.

And since `start_date` is the join condition, you probably don't want all three references; and to get the zeros in the result set you'll need to NVL the failure and warning counts, so you might as well use unquoted identifiers anyway:

```
Select a.start_date "Start date", a."Successes",
  nvl(b.failures, 0) "Failures", nvl(c.warnings, 0) "Warnings"
...
                    NVL(count(job_id),0) as successes
...
```

The NVL you already have around the count isn't doing anything though - it needs to be in the outer query instead as shown - because there is no start date value to group by if the count is null.

---

If the subqueries really are so similar you could simplify this to a single query level with three selective counts; something like:

```
Select to_char(Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
    WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
    WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
    WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
  END, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as "Start date",
  count(case when State = 1 then job_id end) as "Successes",
  count(case when State = 3 then job_id end) as "Failures",
  count(case when State = 2 then job_id end) as "Warnings"
from NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V
where (:P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Tiny'
    AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 1)
  OR (:P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Small'
    AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 1
    AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 5)
  OR (:P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Medium'
    AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 5
    AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) <= 20)
  OR (:P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER = 'Large'
    AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 20)
  OR (:P1_JOB_SIZE_CHOOSER NOT IN ('Small','Medium','Large','Tiny') 
    AND (1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) > 0)
group by Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
    WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
    WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
    WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
  END
order by Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
    WHEN 'Daily' THEN trunc(start_time)
    WHEN 'Weekly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'WW')
    WHEN 'Monthly' THEN trunc(start_time, 'MM') 
  END;
```

Your parentheses seem to be out of whack too, so I've attempted to correct those, but you may have been doing something intentional I didn't follow...

Comment: @Philab - I've added a version without the subqueries and joins - I think it's equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`Select a.START_DATE, a.Successes, b.START_DATE, b.Failures, c.START_DATE, ...`
by 
`Select a."START_DATE", a."Successes", b."START_DATE", b."Failures", c."START_DATE", ...`